# Is there a query string character whose meaning is "ignore the string beyond this point"?

Tags: url, query-string

Is there a reserved query-string character that is conventionally used to ignore sections of the string? Something like this:

```
?foo=bar&baz=quux*some character*&sky=blue
```

Where adding *some character* results in this query string with the end ignored:

```
?foo=bar&baz=quux
```

I know that it's usually up to the programs parsing the query string to decide how anything is handled, but I wanted to know if anything like this exists in the same way that a + is meant to denote a space.

Comment: Please elaborate *ignore*? Who should not be aware that something came after this character. And perhaps more importantly, who should know that something was comming after this character.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [fragment identifier, indicated by `#`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.5), has such an [effect](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.4):

> The query component is indicated by the first question
> mark ("`?`") character and terminated by a number sign ("`#`") character
> or by the end of the URI.